# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getMorphClass()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, relationship

DB structure:

```
items ( id, ... )
photos ( id, ... )
comments ( id, entity_id, entity_type )
```

where `entity_type` is an `ENUM ('Item', 'Photo')`

Models:

```
class Item extends Eloquent {
  public function comments() {
    return $this->morphMany('Comment', 'entity');
  }
}
class Photo extends Eloquent {
  // same as Item
}
class Comment extends Eloquent {
  public function entity() {
    return $this->morphTo();
  }
}
```

For some reason when I try this:

```
$comments = $item->comments()->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();
```

I get this error.

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getMorphClass()
```

It seems like it's trying to use the Query Builder instead of MorphOneOrMany, which does have getMorphClass defined. But even if I simply do `$item->comments` without any further query building, it gives the same error.

Comment: What version of the framework?

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Not sure, but I started this project 7-8 months ago. But I was looking at the latest version documentation when I added the morph stuff above, so it was probably out of date by then. Updated the framework and it seems to be working. That was a nice use of 100 reputation -_-

Comment: You can see the version number in your composer.json file

Answer (score 1):

Here's the documentation on Polymorphic relations: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#polymorphic-relations

If I understand correctly, a comment can be used on an `Item` or a `Photo`. The models you pasted were setup correctly for that.

In order to sort relationships you can use a closure like this:

```
$item = Item::with(array('comments' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('created_at');
}))->find($id);

// These will be sorted:
$item->comments;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my temporary solution

```
class Item extends Eloquent {
  public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany('Comment', 'entity_id')
      ->where('entity_type', '=', 'Item');
  }
}
```

I would really prefer to use `morphMany` though.